# Can we make it so that we can vote on questions and answers with the keyboard?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, accessibility

When reviewing one of my recent questions, I wanted to tab through the question to upvote one of the answers a poster provided.  However, it appears that downvotes and upvotes aren't accessible through tab.  Why is this?

Can we make it so that we can vote with the keyboard (using tab and spacebar)?

---

Sidenote:
Also just found I can't add comments via tabbing on the keyboard...

Another Sidenote:
I can't accept an answer via tabbing on the keyboard...

Comment: All you need to do is ask :P http://stackapps.com/questions/2567/official-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: @Lix Ironically, the official keyboard shortcuts "vote" command seems to be failing on this question (at least for me).

Comment: @jer - [seems to be working for me](http://i.imgur.com/sDgFe.png)

Comment: @JeremyBanks It works for me fine as well ^_^

Comment: @Lix - wow - I love the official-keyboard-shortcuts!  That does everything I need to through the keyboard.  Should I delete this post or do you think it's worth getting the voting and comments to be "tab-able"?

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Doesn't work for me either. I'm running Google Chrome, you too?

Comment: @TomWijsman - I just installed the "version with update check" in Chrome and it's working for me

Comment: @Zac - Well... it does already exist... But you might be able to squeeze a few more upvotes ;)

Comment: @ZackMacomber: Ah, that one wanted to install a new one on every visit, probably a bug with Tampermonkey. Will update it soon, there was a probably related to blocking the historic votes...

Comment: I know this is really a year old, but I want to comment that people who need to access sites with keyboard control only, shouldn't be forced to learn 'official keyboard shortcuts' - nice as they are.  Websites should be made to be accessible using standard techniques as much as possible.

Comment: @Tsundoku You may want to consider [turning on keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site).

Comment: @Spevacus That feature is much too obscure to be of any use to anyone, except people who visit SE every day.

Answer (score 4):

This is mostly implemented. You can use <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to vote on (or accept) posts, but <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> does not work (even though [it should because that's a `<button>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#keyboard-interaction-3); it even flickers). Still, it's good enough now that even people who are completely blind can (and do!) use the site.

You don't need to change any settings for that, but there is an additional option for [dedicated keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current).

Comment: What do you know...9 years later and now able to upvote with the keyboard...cool...