# Keyboard shortcuts are now integrated into the site

Tags: discussion, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts, announcements

[Originally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102769/keyboard-shortcuts-phase-one) we had implemented keyboard shortcuts as a user script. We have now finally made the change to have them integrated into the site.

When you go to the *Edit Profile & Settings* page on your profile, and then select the *Preferences* submenu, you’ll find a new checkbox labeled *Enable keyboard shortcuts* (which is located about half the way down on that page). Click it, and from there on, everything works as with the user script. Press <kbd>?</kbd> to get started.

[Once you enable it on one site, it's enabled cross-network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312501/new-global-preferences-keyboard-shortcuts-and-sticky-topbar).

**If you already have the user script installed** you don’t need to do anything. We detect the user script, disable its functionality, and run the built-in version instead. That means you don't have to manually enable anything, while still running the correct version of the keyboard shortcuts (currently the two are identical, but in the future, fixes and improvements will be made to the built-in version).

Comment: @rene No, it should work (and does, for me, on MSO).

Comment: W0000t! About time!

Comment: Just to note: The [Pro Forma Autoreview Comments extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoreviewcomments/denkbaalahjlbbfnifkacdigaofcnogg) interferes with comment loading for now.

Comment: @rene I don't know where you see caching playing a role here, but yes, I can confirm it's indeed broken on MSO in IE11.

Comment: “You'll have to make this change on every Stack Exchange site that you're active on.” [NOOOOOO!!!](http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120616003315/random-ness/images/9/9f/Darth_vader_no.gif)

Comment: _"We just don't currently have a cross-site preference infrastructure..."_ But authorizing Stack Exchange API applications is a network-wide action... :)

Comment: -1 for making me enable this on *every* site! You should just integrate it with the profile page so you can push to all sites if you want to. Really? :(

Comment: Next up: a userscript to change this on all your sites for you.

Comment: @fredley Such a script already exists, see the last paragraph.

Comment: @rene The IE issue is fixed now.

Comment: Mini-feature-request: Make `j`/`k` work on `s`earches too

Comment: When you copy your profile across, couldn't some settings be copied too?

Comment: It did not work for me in Firefox (probably because I have option *"Search for text when I start typing"* turned on).

Comment: Or rather, it does if I use Shift + whatever shortcut key. Where is that documented? I only discovered it by accident, by reading [another Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315786).

Comment: Firefox version: Quantum 62.0

Comment: To make it work *reliably* in Firefox (say, for use with macro keyboards and other kinds of macros), the ***existing view state*** (e.g., the focus may be in some UI element that prevents the Stack Exchange keyboards from working) in Firefox needs to be ***reset*** to a known (good) state. This can be done by this sequence: Ctrl + F, Esc, F6, F6. Explanation: The toggle F6 + F6 (to the address bar and back) clears the state and Ctrl + F, Esc is for the toggle to end up in the main window (as the toggle would fail for this purpose if the focus when this starts happens to be in the address bar).

Comment: The F6 toggle may not be necessary. *Ctrl*  *F*, *Esc* may be sufficient.

Answer (score 18):

Will these keyboard shortcuts help me <s>robo-</s>review faster?

Comment: After a quick look at the help dialog when reviewing some edits, and trying out some combinations, it looks like you cannot access review options using keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: You can, however, use [my userscript](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/Inferno/tree/master/nonmod/review-shortcuts) for that. </shameless-plug>

Comment: Related: [Keyboard shortcuts for review queues](/q/242001) and [Fully enable keyboard shortcuts in review queues](/q/315782).

Answer (score 12):

Could support also be added for comments (upvote, flag, edit, delete)?

Comment: you can use tab navigation

Answer (score 11):

Methinks the Help Centers should be updated to mention this feature.

Answer (score 7):

Could we make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> unified across the text inputs?

When you edit an answer or question you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and finish (same as sending an email on gmail). This works in a couple of other places, but not when you are submitting a question or answer, you have to physically click the button.

<sub>This is taken from my question [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11652/sometimes-ctrlenter-works-sometimes-not)</sub>

Comment: sounds like a different [tag:feature-request] to me :P

Answer (score 7):

Since this intended for power-users can we get a way to get to the review-pages as well as the "hidden pages" like the 10k-tools (or site-stats)? And can we get working navigation while we're on these pages?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>t</kbd> opens the tag section, but doesn't scroll to it or focus it, making it little more than useless.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some screenshots for the "Order answers by..." (at least for the user script).  What happened to that function? I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot more handy shortcuts:

Why can I use keyboard shortcuts when I answer in threads (which has a WYSIWYG) but cannot use the same shortcuts in comments?

Do you realize how long it takes to put a link in a comment? 
I first have to paste the link's string and then manually wrap it in `[]` and then add the hyperlink `(..)` this is extremely tedious.

In here I just select the text, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and that's it.

The most *killer feature* of all would be to **automatically** transform a link's text into the title of that page, so the link will have a readable meaning and not just a long string of meaningless characters/numbers

Comment: The editor's keyboard shortcuts are not related to this feature, and are enabled regardless.

Comment: You misread what I've said - I was talking about comments, not editor (for answering). There are no markdown shortcuts inside comments.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. The editor hotkeys you wish to emulate in comments do not come from this script, or its integration into SE. There's therefore no point in posting *here*, on this question, to ask for those same hotkeys to be added to comments: they were never part of the script in the first place and the code is not related.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - I know it's not related to this script and I know that those shortcuts come directly from the 3rd-party WYSIWYG editor, but still, why not add focus-aware shortcuts? There's nothing in the title of this topic to suggest this is not the right place. I ***almost*** wrote a script myself that works on stackoverflow and allow much more useful shortcuts than the ones provided already. but I do not wish to spend time on something which I believe should be integrated internally, so I'm here to promote my agenda

Comment: a) There already are such scripts. I use one myself. Look on https://stackapps.com. b) If you answer only by a question's title, without reading the actual question, you will *very frequently* end up completely missing the point. On many sites, such answers are deletion-fodder. c) Just post a question already. It's not that hard. (Better yet, [find the existing question and upvote it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14756/formatting-keyboard-shortcuts-for-comments).)