# Add "go to... Review" as a keyboard shortcut

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently found out about [keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/announcement-keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site), they're truly awesome!

One place I often visit, but has no shortcut yet, is [the review menu](https://stackoverflow.com/review). I'd suggest adding this by pressing `g (go to...)` + `r (review)`. I bet the few clicks it saves us really adds up over time.

**Edit:**

After hitting [2k rep on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235594/thechamp), I am reviewing a lot more than before, as I'm going for the [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor) badge.

This shortcut would definitely improve the experience for myself & other reviewers.

**2nd Bounty:**

After getting the Copy Editor badge, this is still a much needed feature. Let us tweak 'em [keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/announcement-keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site)!

Comment: Aren't keyboard shortcuts for *frequently* used things? Or things which are otherwise troublesome to navigate to.

Comment: Define *frequently* used. I for sure use reviews frequently.

Comment: The review link is right at the top of every single page, and is only one click, so didn't think it worthwhile really. With reviews for Help and support, triage, and usually suggested edits I usually manage to reach my daily review cap on one, sometimes two, visits. But fair enough if you do use it frequently,  fair play - we're all different (hence no downvote).

Comment: The profile is also a shortcut and on top of every page. But ye, everyone has its own taste, we'll see what the others have to say ;)

Comment: You know what, 16 others like it, no-one has not (no dvote), and I can see this being useful for many users, and if it gets people reviewing even a bit more then why not. You convinced me :) +1

Comment: Great, appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a regular reviewer, I agree that this would be a very useful shortcut to have, and I think it should be added to the standard shortcut functionality on Stack Exchange sites.

In the meantime, I've written [a userscript](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/8660-go-to-review/) ([direct link](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/8660-go-to-review/code/Go%20To%20Review.user.js)/[source](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/8660-go-to-review/)) that adds this shortcut to all sites where you have the ability to review posts.

Comment: Does it work on beta sites?

Comment: @FollowMyProposals I don't have review privileges on any beta sites, but it definitely should.

Comment: Cool! So you press g and r at the same time? Do you need to press control or anything?

Comment: Nope; you just have to press "g" and then "r" (you don't have to press them at the same time).

Comment: OK. I tried it. It didn't work on ELL SE.

Comment: @FollowMyProposals I've posted an updated version of the script that should handle the buttons better; see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the script! It will suffice for now :) Though I hope to see the official shortcut in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

AstroCB's user script is great! Should implied soon but...

Pressing `g` then `r` might be weird as shortcuts usually use the `Shift` button. I recommend using `Shift` then `r`. Just make sure you're not typing or you go directly to the review queues... This would help users get used to the shortcut quicker. There aren't many shortcuts that doesn't use `Shift` anyways.

This would be a lovely application in the future. In some betas whereas users battle to keep their spots in the leaderboards ***and*** most importantly, review what needs to be review, this can help save time! This can also help high-traffic sites to finish those awaiting reviews as fast as possible. You should know about the growing Close Votes in Stack Overflow...

For the better future of all reviewers, I say the official shortcut should be launched!

Comment: The shortcuts aren't activated while writing. They only trigger when not focused on an input field. The same complication would happen when going to the homepage via `g` + `h` etc...