# Add a keyboard shortcut to visit a review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, accessibility, keyboard-shortcuts

Since I have the privilege, I visit the review queues a lot.  It would save a lot of clicks if we had a keyboard shortcut to access the review queues.  It should go like:

1. <kbd>G</kbd> to `go to...`
2. <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Review Queues dropdown.
3. Keys 1 through 4 to access the close votes, edits, VLQ and reopen votes queues, and the others for the other SE sites.

Yes, I think this would be a good feature.  Can we add this to the shortcut system?

Comment: Related: [Add "go to... Review" as a keyboard shortcut](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245009/294691)