# Keyboard shortcuts start working only after the page finish loading

Tags: bug, usability, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently discovered [keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/announcement-keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site) and have been using them extensively since then.

Unfortunately, I find that they don't work reliably for precisely the scenario where they would be particularly useful.

As a [Charcoal HQ participant](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) I flag a lot of spam.  Often, you can tell already before clicking that the post is a spam (the summary posted in the chat room is often sufficient) ... but you have to wait for the page to load completely, including any ads, before the keyboard shortcuts actually work.

Even then, if you are quick enough, sometimes a keystroke is missed because it happens precisely when the JavaScript draws a pseudo-dialog or something (this is my very ad-hoc analysis; I don't really pretend to understand this stuff in particular, or JavaScript in general) and then you have to try again, again, because of that.

Is there any way the keyboard shortcuts could be loaded into the page at an earlier stage, or some other workaround so that you could queue in a bunch of keystrokes and let the computer catch up with your Fastest Gun in the West?

For the record, a typical sequence is <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> (downvote; flag as spam) and you get a pseudo-dialog "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved" after the downvote (if your rep on the site isn't above the threshold where you don't get this; maybe there are other scenarios, too?).  Sometimes the downvote is lost and spam flagging succeeds, sometimes it's the other way around, and sometimes I just have to do the whole sequence a second, or even a third or fourth time.

Comment: I could abstain from downvoting but that's a separate discussion.  The central problem is that keystrokes are lost if you are too fast.

Comment: Guess it's by design, to not cause the page contents to load slower.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks.  But then maybe that line of reasoning should be revisited. If it adds 0.2s load time but allows me to not wait for 2-3s load times, it's a win.  People who don't like that can turn it off again, after all.

Comment: Thing is, I believe the JS file is loaded anyway, so it adds another complexity.