# Keyboard shortcuts don't work with a Russian keyboard layout

Tags: feature-request, localization, keyboard-shortcuts, russian-stackoverflow, internationalization

For example, with a Russian layout we can open only the Help window with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd>. Even for this we have to use a different button on the keyboard (the <kbd>?</kbd> on <kbd>7</kbd> button).

But the rest of the shortcuts don't work at all. It's kind of annoying to switch layout every time I need to use shortcuts.

Can the website please be modified to accept Cyrillic equivalents of Latin script characters for keyboard shortcuts, so that it works properly for the Russian keyboard layout?

Related: [Горячие клавиши не работают в русской раскладке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5916/15479).

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It gave me the hint on how to make [the keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166) work on Firefox - use the Shift key. E.g. Shift + V to bring up the list with the two choices "U" and "D" (for upvote and downvote).

Comment: @PeterMortensen glad, I helped someone)

Comment: It could be because the website is expecting the characters in Latin script, whereas the same characters are transmitted in Cyrillic script when using a Russian keyboard layout.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog thanks for editing)

Comment: Probably it can be easily implemented for any language, if developers will use [`event.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) (or [`event.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)) instead of [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)