# If someone is tabbing around the site, offer to turn on keyboard shortcuts

Tags: feature-request, status-review, accessibility, navigation, keyboard-shortcuts

Turning on keyboard shortcuts... isn't the simplest thing to do. You have to either previously know about them, or happen to stumble upon them buried deep in your settings.

This isn't really helpful from an accessibility viewpoint, if all your helpful keyboard shortcuts are impossible to turn on.

What would solve this problem is by being able to turn them on directly from the main site as well as in your settings.

If the site notices that a user is using <kbd>tab</kbd> to get around, it should offer to turn on keyboard shortcuts for them. This could be accomplished with a popup - with the focus properly transferred to the popup, of course - or a hidden option that only shows up when the <kbd>tab</kbd> focus lands on it, much like Google's "accessibility help" thing.

Comment: Re *Turning on keyboard shortcuts... isn't the simplest thing to do*: Indeed. The same with discovery that they exist at all.

Comment: Why shouldn't they turned on by default?

Comment: There are keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: @TheWanderer: They are enabled in [preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) (under *"SITE SETTINGS"* (third group in the left panel) → *"Preferences"*). See also *[Keyboard shortcuts are now integrated into the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166)* (2014). [Screenshot of keyboard shortcuts](https://stackapps.com/questions/2567/official-keyboard-shortcuts) (somewhat out of date). Press `?` to get the list displayed.

Comment: The new sticky top bar also rears its ugly head here: The start of the list (by "?") is not visible at ***high zoom levels*** (from the third-to-last zoom level before the right panel disappears on the system I am currently using). Not even if scrolled all the way to the top (from the second-to-last zoom level before the right panel disappears). There is plenty of space for it on the screen.