# Class .keyboard-selected remains after selection ends

Tags: bug, design, keyboard-shortcuts

With [keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site) enabled, to reproduce:

1. Go to any question (including this one).
2. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to enter the edit mode.
3. Cancel the edit.
4. Select anything else with your mouse or keyboard

The `.keyboard-selected` class is not removed and the shadow remains on the post that was auto-selected for the edit.

I'm able to reproduce this behavior in Chrome and Edge on Windows 10 (I haven't tried other OSes).

Comment: Side note, I stumbled upon this feature. I thought I had somehow deleted the post I was on because the shadow was foreign and the shadow somewhat resembles a deleted post's opacity change.

Comment: Can't repro with editing, but other actions (i.e. voting) repro