# Show Hot Network Questions on Unanswered Questions page

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, hot-questions

On the Unanswered Questions tab on the questions page (for example https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) the list of Hot Network Questions is shown underneath the Related Tags section in the right sidebar.

However, on the Unanswered Questions page (for example https://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered) the HNQ is not shown. This page is the target for the [keyboard shortcut](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site) <kbd>G</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> that I use very often, so I would like to see the HNQ on this page as well.

Why is there a difference between the two pages? Can HNQ be added to [/unanswered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered) as well?

Answer (score -2):

What "hot network questions"? On the sites where I have accounts? All sites? My favourite sites (defined somehow, I might be very active in some sites, and just occasionally peek at others)?

If not filtered somehow, this gets to be just so much extra spam.

Comment: Hot Network Questions or HNQ is a list of "automatically selected recent questions from the Stack Exchange network. They are shown in the right-hand panel in the desktop version of the site", see the [glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40354/) at the letter H. See https://imgur.com/a/RcySt0n for an example from the Unaswered Questions tab that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: So to be clear, this is a list of questions that is automatically selected, and it is the same for everybody, it is not linked to your personal account. It is only shown on the desktop version of the site, so it is not visible on a mobile phone or a tablet. There are 100 questions on the list at any time (see https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) from which a selection is shown in the right sidebar at many places on the site, but not on the Unanswered Questions page that I was asking about.

Comment: Many people in fact don't like the HNQ list, there is a preference setting in your profile to disable it. However, I do like the feature, and I would like to see it at the Unanswered Questions page too.