# Keyboard shortcut navigation stops working when changing page in the question/answer page for a user

Tags: bug, navigation, keyboard-shortcuts

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Go to a user's questions or answers page. Important, there have to be multiple pages of posts.
2. Go to any other page. Important: do *not* reload the page.
3. Use [keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237166/keyboard-shortcuts-are-now-integrated-into-the-site) to navigate. For example <kbd>J</kbd> to select next post.

**Expected**: keyboard navigation to select the required post from the list. For example, sequential starting from the top for <kbd>J</kbd>.

**Actual**: The screen jitters any time <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, or <kbd>U</kbd> is pressed but nothing is selected.

**Demonstration**:

Going to my answer, pressing <kbd>J</kbd> 5 times, scrolling to the end, going to the next page and pressing <kbd>J</kbd> 4 times: [see GIF here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ65Z.gif).

**Workaround**: refreshing the browser tab with the correct `page=<number>` in the URL would load directly to that page in the table and keyboard selection works again until the next time the table page is changed.

The issue seems to be related to the in-place change of table pages.